# What is the best way to automatically generate JUnit results in xml?

Tags: java, xml, junit

I am currently writing a series of tests in JUnit. I need to automatically export the results as XML. I was reading that the best way of doing this is by extending the RunListener class and writing the XML that way.  Below is a sample of what I have done so far, but I am struggling with how to extract information on each test that has been run.  The 'Description' class doesn't seem to have any useful get methods and I feel like I am maybe going about this the wrong way.

Can someone assist with how to get useful information from description (eg. test passed / failed, duration of test, test name etc) or give me some advice on what I actually should be doing?

```
public class XmlListener extends RunListener {

    private final PrintStream fWriter;

    public XmlListener(JUnitSystem system) {
        this(system.out());
    }

    public XmlListener(PrintStream writer) {
        this.fWriter = writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) {
        fWriter.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) {
        fWriter.append("\t\t</suite>\n");
        fWriter.append("\t</suites>\n");
        fWriter.append("</result>\n");
        printHeader(result.getRunTime());
        printFailures(result);
        printFooter(result);

    }

    @Override
    public void testStarted(Description description) {
        fWriter.append("\t\t\t<case>\n");
        fWriter.append("\t\t\t\t<timestamp>"  + "</timestamp>\n");
        fWriter.append("\t\t\t\t<className>"  + "</className>\n");
        fWriter.append("\t\t\t\t<testName>"  + "</testName>\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void testFinished(Description description) {
        fWriter.append("\t\t\t\t<duration>"  + "</duration>\n");
        fWriter.append("\t\t\t</case>\n");
        Iterator it = description.getAnnotations().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            fWriter.append(it.next().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) {
        fWriter.append('E');
    }

    @Override
    public void testIgnored(Description description) {
        fWriter.append('I');
    }

    /**
     * private methods
     * @return
     */

    private PrintStream getWriter() {
        return fWriter;
    }

    protected void printHeader(long runTime) {
        getWriter().println();
        getWriter().println("Time: " + elapsedTimeAsString(runTime));
    }

    protected void printFailures(Result result) {
        List<Failure> failures= result.getFailures();
        if (failures.size() == 0)
            return;
        if (failures.size() == 1)
            getWriter().println("There was " + failures.size() + " failure:");
        else
            getWriter().println("There were " + failures.size() + " failures:");
        int i= 1;
        for (Failure each : failures)
            printFailure(each, "" + i++);
    }

    protected void printFailure(Failure each, String prefix) {
        getWriter().println(prefix + ") " + each.getTestHeader());
        getWriter().print(each.getTrace());
    }

    protected void printFooter(Result result) {
        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            getWriter().println();
            getWriter().println("\t</suites>\n");
            getWriter().println("</result>\n");
            getWriter().println(" (" + result.getRunCount() + " test" + (result.getRunCount() == 1 ? "" : "s") + ")");

        } else {
            getWriter().println();
            getWriter().println("FAILURES!!!");
            getWriter().println("Tests run: " + result.getRunCount() + ",  Failures: " + result.getFailureCount());
        }
        getWriter().println();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the formatted string of the elapsed time. Duplicated from
     * BaseTestRunner. Fix it.
     */
    protected String elapsedTimeAsString(long runTime) {
        return NumberFormat.getInstance().format((double) runTime / 1000);
    }
}
```

UPDATE - Ant build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="COTPlus" default="main" basedir=".">
<property name="src.dir" location="src" />

<target name="test" >
<junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="false">
  <formatter type="xml" />
  <batchtest todir="/test-reports">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/ExampleTest.java"  />
  </batchtest>
</junit>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="test">
        <description>Main target</description>
        <echo>${src.dir}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using maven for your project?  You get surefire-reports for free with maven, and those include very detailed XML reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Ant Script to get XML Results

```
<target name="test" >

 <javac srcdir="/src"
     destdir="/bin"
     classpath="/lib/junit.jar"  />


<junit haltonfailure="false">
  <formatter type="xml" />
  <batchtest todir="/test-reports">
    <fileset dir="/bin" includes="tests/ExampleTest.class"  />
  </batchtest>
</junit>
</target>
```

this will Generate an xml into the /test-reports Folder. More Details on Ant Builds http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html

Comment: I have tried this but I get a ClassNotFoundException.  The ant task seems to run and it can find the file, but then complains about a missing class. I have tried googling how to fix this but no luck.  I have attached my ant build file above.

Comment: You need to compile the .java file First. I'll Update my Answer