# After running JUnit tests in eclipse, I can export the result in XML format. How can I get that xml file using JUnit command line?

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have Java unit tests which I run using JUnit plugin in Eclipse. After all tests are completed in eclipse, I can export the result in .xml format which I use it to upload the results in test result tracking tool.

Now I am running same tests in AIX system where I am using command line to run JUnit tests.

My command is

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.rsa.qa.sae.test.testClassName
```

Now I want to get results of these tests in a similar XML file.

How can I get it?

Comment: Do you get result output in console?

Comment: From Eclipse, I get output in .xml format. It exports the file. I want in similar way from command prompt.

Comment: thats what I asked, if you are getting output in console, you can redirect it to file easily.

Answer (score 3):

The base JUnit library doesn't produce reports.  Various libraries that run JUnit do ([Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), Eclipse, etc etc).

If you can't/won't use those tools, then you need to generate the report yourself by implementing a [`RunListener`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html), and creating your own main method that registers it with `JUnitCore`.  Using that you can generate the XML in whatever form you'd like.

Similar questions:

- [Generate XML Files Used by JUnit Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062412/generate-xml-files-used-by-junit-reports)
- [Generating JUnit reports from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445582/generating-junit-reports-from-the-command-line)